# Is it valid to have form name "<controller_as_identifier><dot><namespaced_form_name>"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

So, the code like this:

```
<form ng-controller="MyCtrl as myCtrl"
      name="myCtrl.form">
    <button type="button"
            ng-click="myCtrl.logScope()"
        >log scope</button>
</form>
...
controller('MyCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.logScope = function() {
            console.log($scope);
        }
        ....

    }]);
```

Outputs to console that the form was published successfuly under `$scope.myCtrl.form`. So, does anyone use such syntax, is it intended / valid to do this way? `Angular 1.5`

Comment: name="myCtrl.form" would assign name="myCtrl.form" as a string, and not an interpolated value from the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use ContrllerAs syntax, you assign all your contoller logic to viewmodel
they put the (vm) varible defined under $scope .

the thing to use controllerAs or the use just scope is that 
when you use $scope you attach new varibles under .

using `var vm=this`
you attach the whole varible under $scope

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely valid as you can see from th screenshot.

[image: W3C Validator]